# Cent OS - How to utilize multiple IP address for web bots?

Tags: linux, hosting, centos, vps

I'm a PHP webbot dev and I often see that VPS services offer multiple IP addresses for their customers.

My question is how can I utilize these extra IPs for my web bots that I create?

(Assuming centos, etc)

Let me know if you need more information to answer my question as I know it's somewhat vague but I'm not very knowledge-able in how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind to a specific address instead of `0.0.0.0` or `::`.